# string manipulations in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

Let's say I have the following column in my data set:

```
fruits<-data.frame(Fruits=c(c("Apples; Oranges; Bananas"),
                            c("Plums; Apples"),
                            c("Satsumas; Plums"),
                            c("Apricots/Peaches; Avocados"),
                            c("Avocados; Oranges")))
```

Where each row is an observation. How could I get the following from my data fruits:

[image]

where the following happens:

1. Unique names of fruits become column names. Forward slash `/` in `Apricots/Peaches` is not replaced by a dot.
2. For each observation, if that type of fruit was in the original string a value, `1` is entered and `0` otherwise. For example, `Apples` appear in observations `1` and `2` only.
3. The first entry of the string `c("Plums; Apples")` is `"Plums"` and it should be recognised as `"Plums"` even if it is the subsequent entry in the string and has a space before the word it as in `c("Satsumas; Plums")`.

Comment: `splitstackshape::cSplit_e(fruits, 'Fruits', sep = ';', type = 'character', fill = 0, drop = TRUE)`

Comment: @RonakShah - this is great, thank you! Any idea on how to get names as Apples instead of Fruits_Apples?